# Bootstrap4 Collapse

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, css3, bootstrap

Как сделать так чтобы если одна копка нажата другие вкладки закрывались

```html
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <title>Hello, world!</title>
    <!-- Required meta tags -->
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, shrink-to-fit=no">

    <!-- Bootstrap CSS -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0-beta.2/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-PsH8R72JQ3SOdhVi3uxftmaW6Vc51MKb0q5P2rRUpPvrszuE4W1povHYgTpBfshb" crossorigin="anonymous">
  </head>
  <body>
        <div class="container-fluid  p-0 mx-0 my-3">
        <div class="row p-0 m-0">
            <div class="w-100 p-0">
                 <div class="btn-group btn-block" role="group" aria-label="Basic example">
                 <button type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#collapseExample" aria-expanded="true" aria-controls="collapseExample" class="btn btn-secondary  btn-sm  fs-text-five">
                  Детали
                 </button>
                 <button type="button"  data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#collapseExample2" aria-expanded="false" aria-controls="collapseExample2"  class="btn btn-secondary  btn-sm  fs-text-five">
                  Особености
                </button>
                <button type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#collapseExample3" aria-expanded="false" aria-controls="collapseExample3" class="btn btn-secondary  btn-sm  fs-text-five">
                  Описание
                </button>
                <button type="button"  class="btn btn-secondary  btn-sm  fs-text-five">
                  Карта
                </button>
                 </div>
            </div>
        </div>
      </div>
<div class="container-fluid ">
        <div class="row">
    <div class="w-100 text-center collapse" id="collapseExample">
      <table class="table table-striped">
        <tbody>
          <tr>
            <td>Mark</td>
            <td>Otto</td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td>Jacob</td>
            <td>Thornton</td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td>Larry</td>
            <td>the Bird</td>
          </tr>
        </tbody>
      </table>
    </div>
    <div class="w-100 text-center collapse" id="collapseExample2">
      <table class="table table-striped">
        <tbody>
          <tr>
            <td>Masdvdsrk</td>
            <td>Otdvsvto</td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td>Jacosdvsdvb</td>
            <td>Thovsdvrnton</td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td>Larsdvsdry</td>
            <td>thevsddsv Bird</td>
          </tr>
        </tbody>
      </table>
    </div>
    <div class="w-100 text-center collapse" id="collapseExample3">
      <p>fvrthrth rhtrthr thrthrt rthtrh trhrthrth</p>
    </div>
    </div>
  </div>  

    <!-- Optional JavaScript -->
    <!-- jQuery first, then Popper.js, then Bootstrap JS -->
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-KJ3o2DKtIkvYIK3UENzmM7KCkRr/rE9/Qpg6aAZGJwFDMVNA/GpGFF93hXpG5KkN" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.12.3/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-vFJXuSJphROIrBnz7yo7oB41mKfc8JzQZiCq4NCceLEaO4IHwicKwpJf9c9IpFgh" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0-beta.2/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-alpBpkh1PFOepccYVYDB4do5UnbKysX5WZXm3XxPqe5iKTfUKjNkCk9SaVuEZflJ" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
  </body>
</html>
```

тоесть без повторных кликов на туже вкладку

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Используйте Tabs (почитать можно [здесь](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/components/navs/#tabs))

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0-beta.2/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<ul class="nav nav-tabs" id="myTab" role="tablist">
  <li class="nav-item">
    <a class="nav-link active" id="home-tab" data-toggle="tab" href="#home" role="tab" aria-controls="home" aria-selected="true">Home</a>
  </li>
  <li class="nav-item">
    <a class="nav-link" id="profile-tab" data-toggle="tab" href="#profile" role="tab" aria-controls="profile" aria-selected="false">Profile</a>
  </li>
  <li class="nav-item">
    <a class="nav-link" id="contact-tab" data-toggle="tab" href="#contact" role="tab" aria-controls="contact" aria-selected="false">Contact</a>
  </li>
</ul>
<div class="tab-content" id="myTabContent">
  <div class="tab-pane fade show active" id="home" role="tabpanel" aria-labelledby="home-tab">
    <table class="table table-striped">
      <tbody>
        <tr>
          <td>Mark</td>
          <td>Otto</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>Jacob</td>
          <td>Thornton</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>Larry</td>
          <td>the Bird</td>
        </tr>
      </tbody>
    </table>
  </div>
  <div class="tab-pane fade" id="profile" role="tabpanel" aria-labelledby="profile-tab">
    <table class="table table-striped">
      <tbody>
        <tr>
          <td>Masdvdsrk</td>
          <td>Otdvsvto</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>Jacosdvsdvb</td>
          <td>Thovsdvrnton</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>Larsdvsdry</td>
          <td>thevsddsv Bird</td>
        </tr>
      </tbody>
    </table>
  </div>
  <div class="tab-pane fade" id="contact" role="tabpanel" aria-labelledby="contact-tab">
    <p>fvrthrth rhtrthr thrthrt rthtrh trhrthrth</p>
  </div>
</div>

<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-KJ3o2DKtIkvYIK3UENzmM7KCkRr/rE9/Qpg6aAZGJwFDMVNA/GpGFF93hXpG5KkN" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.12.3/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-vFJXuSJphROIrBnz7yo7oB41mKfc8JzQZiCq4NCceLEaO4IHwicKwpJf9c9IpFgh" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0-beta.2/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-alpBpkh1PFOepccYVYDB4do5UnbKysX5WZXm3XxPqe5iKTfUKjNkCk9SaVuEZflJ" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
```